# gwt Visualization: Timeline

Tags: gwt, chap-links-library, gwt-visualization

I wanted to implement gwt visualization timeline chart.

But, its not available in gwt, is it possible to use visualization api (javascript) directly in gwt application.

If yes, please give me some guidance.

Is there any other option available for this.

I tried http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/timeline.html and its good.

But, I wanted to know about the visualization api in gwt.

Comment: You can use any JavaScript library - or native JavaScript - in GWT.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your requirements but this [project](https://code.google.com/p/gwtgantt/) offers a Gantt chart in GWT

Answer (score 0):

I found this one...

http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/gwt/files/examples/TimelineDemo4_offline.zip

I've tried it and it work!!!

Below the main code that you need

```
/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class TimelineDemo4_offline implements EntryPoint {
    final TextBox txtStartDate = new TextBox();
    final TextBox txtEndDate = new TextBox();
    final Button btnSetRange = new Button("Set");
    final CheckBox chkConfirmChange = new CheckBox("Confirm changes");

    Timeline timeline = null;
    JSONArray data = new JSONArray();

    /** 
     * This is the entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        RootPanel.get("txtStartDate").add(txtStartDate);
        RootPanel.get("txtEndDate").add(txtEndDate);
        RootPanel.get("btnSetRange").add(btnSetRange);
        RootPanel.get("chkConfirmChange").add(chkConfirmChange);

        // Add a handler to the add button
        btnSetRange.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                setRange();
            }
        });

        data = createData();

        Timeline.Options options = Timeline.Options.create();
        options.setWidth("100%");
        options.setHeight("300px");
        options.setStyle(Timeline.Options.STYLE.BOX);
        options.setEditable(true);

        // create the timeline, with data and options
        timeline = new Timeline(data.getJavaScriptObject(), options);

        // add event handlers
        timeline.addSelectHandler(createSelectHandler(timeline));
        timeline.addRangeChangeHandler(createRangeChangeHandler(timeline));
        timeline.addChangeHandler(createChangeHandler(timeline));
        timeline.addAddHandler(createAddHandler(timeline));
        timeline.addEditHandler(createEditHandler(timeline));
        timeline.addDeleteHandler(createDeleteHandler(timeline));

        RootPanel.get("mytimeline").add(timeline);

        getRange();
    }

    DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    private long dateToLong(String date) {
        return df.parse(date).getTime();
    }

    DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    private long datetimeToLong(String datetime) {
        return dtf.parse(datetime).getTime();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a table filled with data
     * @return data
     */
    private JSONArray createData() {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject item;

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-08-23")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("<div>Conversation</div><img   src='img/comments-icon.png' style='width:32px; height:32px;'>"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(datetimeToLong("2010-08-23 23:00:00")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("<div>Mail from boss</div><img src='img/mail-icon.png' style='width:32px; height:32px;'>"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(datetimeToLong("2010-08-24 16:00:00")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("Report"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-08-26")));
        item.put("end", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-09-02")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("Traject A"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-08-28")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("<div>Memo</div><img src='img/notes-edit-icon.png' style='width:48px; height:48px;'>"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-08-29")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("<div>Phone call</div><img src='img/Hardware-Mobile-Phone-icon.png' style='width:32px; height:32px;'>"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-08-31")));
        item.put("end", new JSONNumber(dateToLong("2010-09-03")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("Traject B"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        item = new JSONObject(); 
        item.put("start", new JSONNumber(datetimeToLong("2010-09-04 12:00:00")));
        item.put("content", new JSONString("<div>Report</div><img src='img/attachment-icon.png' style='width:32px; height:32px;'>"));
        data.set(data.size(), item);

        return data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the range from the timeline and put it in the textboxes on screen
     */
    private void getRange() {
        Timeline.DateRange range = timeline.getVisibleChartRange();
        DateTimeFormat dtf = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        // set the new startdate and enddate
        txtStartDate.setText(dtf.format(range.getStart()));
        txtEndDate.setText(dtf.format(range.getEnd()));
    }

    /**
     * Get the entered dates from the textboxes on screen, and apply them to
     * the timeline
     */  
    private void setRange() {
        DateTimeFormat datetime = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateTimeFormat date = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date startDate;
        Date endDate;

        // Try to parse the startdate
        try {
            startDate = datetime.parse(txtStartDate.getText());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException err) {
            try {
                startDate = date.parse(txtStartDate.getText());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException err2) {
                Window.alert("I don't understand the startdate that you  entered :(");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Try to parse the enddate
        try {
            endDate = datetime.parse(txtEndDate.getText());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException err) {
            try {
                endDate = date.parse(txtEndDate.getText());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException err2) {
                Window.alert("I cannot make sense of the enddate that you entered :(");
                return;
            }
        }

        timeline.setVisibleChartRange(startDate, endDate);
        timeline.redraw();
    }

    /**
     * add a select handler (the select event occurs when the user clicks on an
     * event)
     * @param timeline
     * @return
     */
    private SelectHandler createSelectHandler(final Timeline timeline) {
        return new SelectHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSelect(SelectEvent event) {
                JsArray<Selection> sel = timeline.getSelections();

                if (sel.length() > 0) {
                    int row = sel.get(0).getRow();
                    String info = "Selected event " + String.valueOf(row);
                    RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                } else {
                    String info = "Select event &lt;nothing&gt; selected";
                    RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                }
            }
        };
    }     

    /**
     * create a RangeChange handler (this event occurs when the user changes the 
     * visible range by moving or scrolling the Timeline).
     * @param timeline
     * @return
     */
    private RangeChangeHandler createRangeChangeHandler(final Timeline timeline) {
        return new RangeChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onRangeChange(RangeChangeEvent event) {
                getRange();      
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * create a change handler (this event occurs when the user changes
     * the position of an event by dragging it).
     * @param timeline
     * @return
     */
    private ChangeHandler createChangeHandler(final Timeline timeline) {
        return new ChangeHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) {
                // retrieve the row number of the changed event
                JsArray<Selection> sel = timeline.getSelections();
                if (sel.length() > 0) {
                    int row = sel.get(0).getRow();

                    boolean confirmChanges = chkConfirmChange.getValue();

                    // request confirmation
                    boolean applyChange = confirmChanges ? 
                            Window.confirm("Are you sure you want to change this event?") :
                                true;

                            if (applyChange) {
                                String info = "Changed event " + String.valueOf(row);
                                RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                            } else {
                                // cancel the change
                                timeline.cancelChange();

                                String info = "Change event " + String.valueOf(row) + " cancelled";
                                RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                            }
                }
            }
        };
    }



    /**
     * create an add handler (this event occurs when the user creates a new
     * event).
     * @param timeline
     * @return
     */
    private AddHandler createAddHandler(final Timeline timeline) {
        return new AddHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onAdd(AddEvent event) {
                // retrieve the row number of the changed event
                JsArray<Selection> sel = timeline.getSelections();
                if (sel.length() > 0) {
                    int row = sel.get(0).getRow();

                    // request confirmation
                    String title = 
                        Window.prompt("Enter a title for the new event", "New event");

                    if (title != null) {
                        // apply the new title
                        JSONValue value = data.get(row);
                        if (value != null && value.isObject() != null) {
                            JSONObject item = value.isObject();

                            item.put("content", new JSONString(title));
                            timeline.setData(data.getJavaScriptObject());

                            String info = "Added event " + String.valueOf(row);
                            RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        // cancel creating new event
                        timeline.cancelAdd();
                        String info = "Add event " + String.valueOf(row) + " cancelled";
                        RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));             
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }



    /**
     * create an edit handler (this event occurs when the user double clicks an
     * event).
     * @param timeline
     * @return
     */
    private EditHandler createEditHandler(final Timeline timeline) {
        return new EditHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onEdit(EditEvent event) {
                // retrieve the row number of the changed event
                JsArray<Selection> sel = timeline.getSelections();
                if (sel.length() > 0) {
                    int row = sel.get(0).getRow();
                    JSONValue value = data.get(row);
                    if (value != null && value.isObject() != null) {
                        JSONObject item = value.isObject();
                        String content = "";
                        if (item.get("content") != null && 
                                item.get("content").isString() != null) {
                            content = item.get("content").isString().stringValue();
                        }

                        // request new title
                        String title = 
                            Window.prompt("Change the title of this event", 
                                    content);

                        if (title != null) {
                            // apply the new title
                            item.put("content", new JSONString(title));
                            timeline.setData(data.getJavaScriptObject());

                            String info = "Edited event " + String.valueOf(row);
                            RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                        }
                        else {
                            // do nothing
                            String info = "Edit event " + String.valueOf(row) + " cancelled";
                            RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));             
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * create an delete handler (this event occurs when the user creates a new
     * event).
     * @param timeline
     * @return
     */
    private DeleteHandler createDeleteHandler(final Timeline timeline) {
        return new DeleteHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onDelete(DeleteEvent event) {
                // retrieve the row number of the changed event
                JsArray<Selection> sel = timeline.getSelections();
                if (sel.length() > 0) {
                    int row = sel.get(0).getRow();

                    boolean confirmChanges = chkConfirmChange.getValue();

                    if (confirmChanges == false) {
                        String info = "Deleting event " + String.valueOf(row);
                        RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                        return; 
                    }

                    // request confirmation
                    boolean applyDelete = confirmChanges ? 
                            Window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this event?") :
                                true;

                            if (applyDelete) {
                                String info = "Deleted " + String.valueOf(row);
                                RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                            } else {
                                // cancel the deletion
                                timeline.cancelDelete();

                                String info = "Deleting event " + String.valueOf(row) + " cancelled";
                                RootPanel.get("lblInfo").add(new Label(info));
                            }          
                }
            }
        };
    }  
}
```